# SFAccountManager file missing

Tags: account, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, ipad

I am currently trying to update old version of Salesforce sdk to newer versions. The old version had `SFAccountManager` in `SalesforceSDKCore` and in the newer versions it is missing. Is this file replaced with some other file in the newer sdk or is it completely ignored. How to overcome the methods that implemented using `SFAccountManager`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The class `SFAccountManager` is no longer used. You should now instead be using `SFUserAccount`. You should be able to look at [this](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/commit/7745a69aab867f65f96a4c12913c6257d2118999) commit to understand the changes and how they will impact your code.

If you face specific issues migrating, please post a follow up question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to update it to latest class. Will post up questions if I find any difficulty. Thanks!

Between, we are using SA_Base.framework. I couldn't find any update on that framework. Is there one or should we rewrite the whole framework? Is there any other framework which is replacement for SA_Base.framework?

Comment: I could see few methods and properties missing in these two files like mobilePinPolicyConfigured which returns Boolean to start monitoring. How to set the identityData, set delegates, call initiateIdentityDataRetrieval etc., 
Do we have any document reagarding the changes between both the files, deprecated methods and how to overcome it? Thanks!